# find control location from window when flow direction is applied

Tags: c#, wpf, point, frameworkelement

i have a control inside the  window.i set flow direction of the control using from right to left.i tried to calculate the control location from  window.

```
Point locationfromWindow = control.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), control);
```

using above  code i found the point but it differ from setted flow direction left to right of control.

Is flow direction of control is affect location from window value? how to  resolve this  problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by "reversing" the value calculated, when FlowDirection is RTL. This means fixing the X coordinate of the locationfromWindow.
Something like this:

```
double correctX = control.X - locationfromWindow.X;
```

If someone has better solution please tell.

Answer (score 0):

above code calculate the location from top right corner. if we need to calculate from top left corner some thing like this

```
Point pt = TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), control);
pt.Offset(-control.ActualWidth, 0);
```

it calculate the point from top left corner. and works perfectly for me